# How to Handle Inject events in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a task that based on injecting events in windows phone , in that I will Get my X and Y coordinates of my Screen from the server and based on that X, Y I want to touch My windows phone screen programmatically.how it's Possible in WP7/WP8.

Comment: By not doing it this way at all. If touching at a specific coordinate corresponds to an action, execute that action. This should be easy to do if you are using MVVM - just call the relevant method on the ViewModel. If the logic is in the code-behind, or worse, inside the event handler, extract the logic to a method that can be called by your service client.

Comment: thanxs for Your Reply , if You Have Example Please Post that hear